# (PYTHON) Manipulating certain portions of URL at user's request

Tags: string, file, python-3.x, url

The download link I want to manipulate is below:

*http://hfrnet.ucsd.edu/thredds/ncss/grid/HFR/**USWC**/**6km**/hourly/RTV/HFRADAR,**_US_West_Coast**,**_6km_**Resolution,_Hourly_RTV_best.ncd?var=u&var=v&north=**47.20**&west=**-126.3600**&east=**-123.8055**&south=**37.2500**&horizStride=1&time_start=**2015-11-01**T00%3A00%3A00Z&time_end=**2015-11-03**T14%3A00%3A00Z&timeStride=1&addLatLon=true&accept=netcdf*

I want to make anything that's in bold a variable, so I can ask the user what coordinates and data set they want. This way I can download different data sets by using this script. I would also like to use the same variables to name the new file that was downloaded ex:USWC6km20151101-20151103.

I did some research and learned that I can use the urllib.parse and urllib2, but when I try experimenting with them, it says "no module named urllib.parse."

I can use the webbrowser.open() to download the file, but manipulating the url is giving me problems

THANK YOU!!

Comment: You want to open browser window with that link or download and save whatever that link points to?

Comment: that link automatically starts downloading data depending on the specifications you give it. So basically I want to have this as a base link in the program and be able to change the parts i bolded, so I can obtain different data sets. The user can just input the north,west,east,and south numbers and the other bolded parts in the link and the download will begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `urllib` you can use `requests` module that makes downloading content **much** easier. The part that makes actual work is just 4 lines long.

```
# first install this module
import requests

# parameters to change
location = {
    'part': 'USWC',
    'part2': '_US_West_Coast',
    'km': '6km',
    'north': '45.0000',
    'west': '-120.0000',
    'east': '-119.5000',
    'south': '44.5000',
    'start': '2016-10-01',
    'end': '2016-10-02'
}

# this is template for .format() method to generate links (very naive method)
link_template = "http://hfrnet.ucsd.edu/thredds/ncss/grid/HFR/{part}/{km}/hourly/RTV/\
HFRADAR,{part2},_{km}_Resolution,_Hourly_RTV_best.ncd?var=u&var=v&\
north={north}&west={west}&east={east}&south={south}&horizStride=1&\
time_start={start}T00:00:00Z&time_end={end}T16:00:00Z&timeStride=1&addLatLon=true&accept=netcdf"

# some debug info
link = link_template.format(**location)
file_name = location['part'] + location['km'] + location['start'].replace('-', '') + '-' + location['end'].replace('-', '')
print("Link: ", link)
print("Filename: ", file_name)

# try to open webpage
response = requests.get(link)
if response.ok:
    # open file for writing in binary mode
    with open(file_name, mode='wb') as file_out:
        # write response to file
        file_out.write(response.content)
```

Probably the next step would be running this in loop on list that contains location dicts. Or maybe reading locations from csv file.

Comment: This helps me a lot! I was wondering exactly what the requests does and if it means I do not need to open the browser itself to start the download.